# Extremely poor sails.js-based web site mobile performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, mobile, sails.js

For my first foray into web development I turned to node.js, specifically the sails.js framework. I've hit a wall when it comes to mobile performance.

The site is [beta.astadke.org](http://beta.astadke.org), and when I try this on any mobile device the performance is unbearable - 10s of seconds to render the page, the twitter bootstrap (v3) menu button essentially does not work, and the site on mobile is essentially unusable.

Since this is my first experience building a web site, I'm having trouble figuring out what might be the issue. I've turned to google pagespeed and the site seems to be fairly OK from that test, but the performance issues remain.

I'm not sure if I've made fundamental mistakes, or if I'm an optimization away from fixing this. I'm looking for help on what the issue might be or what tools I can turn to to further diagnose the issue.

github source for the site: https://github.com/zwrose/deke-list

Comment: for me it took 2~ seconds to load that page on my phone, maybe bad connection?

Comment: I've tried it on multiple devices over both strong wifi and LTE all with the same results. May I ask what phone/browser/network you had success on?

Comment: Galaxy S2 using wifi connection, note that im from europe.